# Pinch zoom in chrome Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-chrome, gestures

The fusuma and libinput-gestures only maps `ctrl++` with pinch-zoom, which isn't what I want, is there a way to have the actual pinch like the gesture for chrome browser?

Thanks.

Comment: This depends on if your Ubuntu or Desktop version supports zooming on webpages, but first, Chrome needs to support zooming in like that on Ubuntu.